# How to fix the positioning of nodes of igraphs when plotting with ggarrange?

Tags: r, ggplot2, igraph

I have 5 igraphs consisting of 120+ nodes, one for each year. The nodes belong to three different categories highlighted by their shape and color. I am running my `ggraph` code in a loop and saving the resulting plots in a list. Then I am using `ggarrange` to combine them into a single plot.

Below is my `ggraph` code that I am using.

```
p <- ggraph(g, layout = 'fr') + 
    geom_edge_arc(aes(alpha=weight),strength = 0.15, show.legend = F) + 
    geom_node_point(aes(shape=Category, color=Category))+
    theme_void()+
    theme(legend.position = "bottom",
          panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          text = element_text(size=18),
          plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
    labs(title = paste0(Year))
  plots[[i]] <- p
```

And following is my `ggarrange` command to combine them.

```
ggarrange(plotlist = plots, ncol = 3, nrow = 2, common.legend = T, legend = 'bottom')
```

**Resulting plot:**
[image]

**Problem** is that the position of nodes is not consistent, for example blue nodes in 2018 and 2019 are on right and on top in 2020 and again on two different positions in the following years.

Is there any way that the nodes can stay in a similar position area (e.g., bottom for blue) in all years?